# Sending data using Angular Material Dialog, without closing it, in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I work with Angular 9, I'm using the dialog feature in Angular Material, examples of which you can see.
I want to send information to the main component at some point, without closing the dialog.
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

Instead of using the following code, I can send the data without closing the dialog

`this.dialogRof.colse(data);`

**example:**

app.component.html:

```
<button (click)="addUser()">
```

app.component.ts:

```
addUser(){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddUser, {
      width: '350px'
    });
}
```

add-user.component.ts:

```
name="Aliakbar";
send(){
  // Send name to app-component without closing add-user-component
}
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: One thing which comes to my mind is to create a service with a `BehaviorSubject`, you will get data in your parent component and set data in the dialog

Comment: I have not worked so far, you introduce a good source

Comment: @igor_c would you please come up with a short answer so that the question can be closed, should it answer OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to create a simple service with which will hold data from the dialog and those data can be got from the parent component.

add-user-dialog.service.ts

```
private name = new BehaviorSubject<string>(undefined);

constructor(
  ...
  private addUserDialogService: AddUserDialogService,
  ...
) {}

getName() {
  return this.name.asObservable();
}

setName(name: string) {
  this.name.next(name);
}
```

add-user.component.ts

```
name = 'Aliakbar';

constructor(
  private addUserDialogService: AddUserDialogService,
) { }

send() {
  this.addUserDialogService.setName(this.name);
}
```

app.component.ts

```
addUserDataSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(
  ...
  private addUserDialogService: AddUserDialogService,
  ...
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.addUserDataSubscription = this.addUserDialogService.getName().subscribe(name => {
    // do what you need with the dialog data
  }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.addUserDataSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean and I got my answer relatively, thank you

Answer (score 1):

add-user-component.ts

```
public name$ = new Subject<string>();

send () {
  this.name$.next(this.name);
}
```

And app.component.ts

```
addUser(){
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddUser, {
    width: '350px'
  });

  dialogRef.componentInstance.name$
    .pipe(takeUntil(dialogRef.afterClosed()))
    .subscribe((name) => {
      console.log(name);
  });
}
```

I'm not sure if takeUntil will work well here, but you need to unsubscribe somehow after you close it.